# Linear regression decimal residuals below and above don't match exactly

Tags: regression, linear

I'm completely new to statistics and I've been trying to learn it by watching some videos:

https://youtu.be/ZkjP5RJLQF4?t=731

In that video, it says that if you sum the top residuals and bottom residuals they should equal zero:

Before I watched this video I had my own dataset containing of 3 decimal values:

| Price (y-axis) | Time (x-axis) |
| --- | --- |
| 12,20 | 09:00 |
| 15,50 | 12:00 |
| 16,60 | 13:00 |

The mean aka best-fit line for this would be:

(12,20+15,50+16,60)/3 = 14,766666666666667

Rounding to 14,77

Calculating the error:

(below mean)
14,77 - 12,20 = -2,57

(above mean)

15,50 - 14,77 =  + 0,73

16,60 - 14,77 = + 1,83

calculating the sum =

0,73 + 1,83 = 2,56

There's a difference of 0,01 between the top and bottom residuals? Is there something I'm missing or is this normal? Without rounding it would be 0,02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding is the culprit. Do it all with fractions to get the exact zero.

$$
x_1=12.2=\dfrac{366}{30}\\
x_2=15.5=\dfrac{465}{30}\\
x_3=16.6=\dfrac{498}{30}\\
\bar x = \dfrac{443}{30}\\
x_1-\bar x = \dfrac{366}{30} - \dfrac{443}{30} = -\dfrac{77}{30}\\
x_2-\bar x = \dfrac{465}{30} - \dfrac{443}{30}= \dfrac{22}{30}\\
x_3-\bar x = \dfrac{498}{30} - \dfrac{443}{30} = \dfrac{55}{30}
$$
Finally, $-\dfrac{77}{30} + \dfrac{22}{30} + \dfrac{55}{30} = \dfrac{0}{30} = 0$.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but where'd you get those 366/30 etc. numbers?

Comment: I tried a couple of guesses until I found a common denominator for all three values and their average.

Comment: I see, I only understand decimal numbers and somehow am missing a deeper understanding of fractions then. Thank you regardless.